# Problem removing 3G mobile broadband dongle on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hardware, 3g, mobile-broadband

I recently upgraded my 3G mobile broadband dongle to a newer model. Ubuntu recognizes it and I can connect/disconnect with no trouble. The problem comes when I try to safely remove the drive by right clicking its icon and choosing "Safely remove drive". When I do this I get a popup that displays the following

```
Unable to stop drive

Error detaching: helper exited with exit code 1: Detaching device /dev/sdc
USB device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.1/usb2/2-4)
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE: FAILED: No such file or directory
(Continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure.)
STOP UNIT: FAILED: No such file or directory
```

I don't really know what to do from here so I generally shutdown then remove the dongle as I do not want to damage it. Is this a common problem? Am I safe to just pull the dongle out after this message. The message is not particularly informative so I am not sure how best to proceed. I never had this problem with the previous model. Any advice would be very much appreciated. The model is identified as HUAWEI TD CARD storage

Comment: Why is your USB modem/dongle showing up as storage? (note `/dev/sdc`)?

Comment: I have no idea. I did not do anything to install it, it just got recognized when I plugged it in and allowed me to connect

Comment: lots of USB wireless broadband adapters have internal storage. typically, the drivers and software needed to make it work are stored on it. i've also seen plenty of adapters that have microsd slots on them.

Comment: I posted this as these devices are pretty common and I was wondering if anyone else had this problem and hopefully a solution.

Comment: I don't know anything about these devices, but... is there something that uses it that can be closed first?  Also, have you tried unmounting rather than safely removing it?

Comment: Not that I am aware. I close my internet connection and at that point I expect it to be free to be removed. It behaves very differently on windows and has an interfacing application to connect and remove but this is not present on ubuntu. It is not a critical problem just a pain to shutdown just to remove hardward safely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tries to synchronize its cache after the device has already been removed. It [is a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/466575) and safe to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a micro SD card or other storage connected via this device then just remove the device. The file manager may just be confused and tries to sync to the read only memory part of the device, which of course will fail. Just handle this device like a mouse or other non storage USB peripherals. You don't try to safely remove them, because there isn't even an option for doing so.

Btw: No, 3G/LTE USB sticks are horrible, there are to much models out there, they look all the same and you don't know which one works and which does not and they look goofy, too. That's why they have to go away. Buy mobile hotspots instead.